# Generating an HMAC in Javascript doesn't match the one generated in python (with utf-8 encoded characters)

Tags: javascript, python, hmac

The python server generates the hmac:

```
dict_payload = {"name": "Emulsión"}
payload = jsonpickle.encode(dict_payload, unpicklable=False)
python_hmac = hmac.new("secret", bytes(payload, "utf-8"), hashlib.sha256,)

returns - 29c7e4b7049a61c24d0f57c402510d6b0c42b15e97981d6ce96b02fdcf913a45
```

and in node js:

```
payload = {"name": "Emulsión"}
crypto
    .createHmac("sha256", "secret")
    .update(payload, "utf8")
    .digest("hex");

returns - 61d834992df9a302d8ca1768d4d04be644ba1c35054b342db3ed29f4b2f1e888
```

seems that in python the `ó` character was replaced by `\u00f3`
how to achieve the same in Javascript?

Comment: Possibly an HMAC is not 1 to 1 unique

Comment: Make sure your payload is a string!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you are dealing with quotes in your input correctly.

```
payload = {"name": "Emulsión"}
str(payload)
```

Gives you:

```
"{'name': 'Emulsión'}"
```

This is not the same as a json string which has double quotes:

```
'{"name": "Emulsión"}'
```

and will lead to a different result. If you ensure your strings are **exactly** the same, you'll get the same result:

```
import hmac 
import hashlib

payload = '{"name": "Emulsión"}'
    
python_hmac = hmac.new(b"secret", bytes(payload, "utf-8"), hashlib.sha256,)

python_hmac.hexdigest()

# '61d834992df9a302d8ca1768d4d04be644ba1c35054b342db3ed29f4b2f1e888'
```

Comment: If I remove the ó char from from the text it works perfectly.

Comment: @MKh you'll need to provide a reproducible example. If I use your original python code without the ó character I get: `674319c10af07fcef74068dbeb70ed1863a86a6351997922bb8dd9dc01bedcf4` while JS gives me: `8b0904fd4ca4abf4f732cbc14dba98de0a7a7002c0e4bc21808542412247aa7f`

Comment: Updated the question: it turns out that in python to stringify a dict `jsonpickle` was used

Comment: @MKh, you can also use `json.dumps(some_dict, ensure_ascii=False)`